# if condition not working inside onClick()

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick

```
public class Admin extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
EditText password;
Button enter;
private int one=1;
private int zero=0;
private String pass;

protected static String PASSWORD="1234";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.password);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    enter=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_enter);
    enter.setOnClickListener(this); 
        }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(zero);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    pass=password.getText().toString();
    if(pass.matches(PASSWORD)){
        setResult(one);
        Admin.this.finish();
    }
    else
        password.setText("");   

}
```

}

When i remove the if condition then it works but with if condition it give me error:"The application Password Manager has been stoped unexpectedly".So anyone who can help me i am thanking him in advance.

Comment: Any exceptions thrown? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: You should post what the exception is in your logcat, it's kind of hard to debug from this. This code works for me it seems. I would also post the XML for your password layout, I'm going to take a guess that there is probably something wrong there. Also, to comment on your coding style, I suggest you use brackets on your `else` statement as well. This can lead to nasty bugs later that are difficult to track down.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
 if(pass.matches(PASSWORD)){
...
}
```

into:

```
 if(pass.equals(PASSWORD)){
...
}
```